# Write action and reducer efficient and clean (react redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have below actions and reducer:

actions:

```
import { OPEN_NODE, CLOSE_NODE, GET_NODES } from '../constants/NodeActionTypes';

export function openNode(path) {
  return {
    type: OPEN_NODE,
    path: path
  };
}

export function closeNode() {
  return {
    type: CLOSE_NODE
  };
}


export function getNodes(path) {
  return {
    type: GET_NODES,
    path: path
  };
}
```

reducer:

```
export default function opener(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case OPEN_NODE:
    var { path } = action
    var {nodes} = getFileList(path)
    return {
      ...state,
      open:true,
      nodes:nodes
    };
  case CLOSE_NODE:
    return {
      ...state,
      open:false
    };
  case GET_NODES:
    var { path } = action
    var {nodes} = getFileList(path)
    return {
      ...state,
      nodes:nodes
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Obviously, `OPEN_NODE` contain `GET_NODES` (only plus `open:true`), but there seems many way to organize the code:

1. pack `GET_NODES` reducer to a function, call this in `OPEN_NODE` , and add `open:true`.
2. modify `openNode` action, send `[OPEN_NODE, GET_NODES]` together , but how to write `switch(action.type)`'s case ?
3. let `OPEN_NODE` reducer dispatch a `getNodes` action to trigger `GET_NODES` reducer

which is best ? Or any another better way?

Comment: you are essentially asking how to compose your reducer. Let me point you to the right direction: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux. understanding this course can help with all four of your redux questions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to keep everything inside your switch statement. If you have 2 similar actions, just refactor into a private function and call it.

In your case, it might be something like:

```
// your reducer helper
const getNodes = (state) => {
 var { path } = action
 var {nodes} = getFileList(path)
 return {
   ...state,
   nodes:nodes
 };
};

// your reducer function
export default function opener(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case OPEN_NODE:
    return { ...getNodes(state), open:true };
  case GET_NODES:
    return getNodes(state);
  // ....
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think option 1 is good too, but any thought about option 2 and 3 ? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the switch statement to execute both actions :

```
export default function opener(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case OPEN_NODE:
  case GET_NODES:
    var { path } = action
    var {nodes} = getFileList(path)
    return {
      ...state,
      nodes:nodes
      open: action.type === OPEN_NODE ? true : state.open
    };
  case CLOSE_NODE:
    return {
      ...state,
      open:false
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good way. If `OPEN_NODE` need more state in future, or  there is something call `OPEN_NODE_2`  need a new state `open2`, the code would be ugly full of `action.type === xxx ? true : xxx`

Comment: If you see this pattern to many times it's effectively a strong signal that you have to refactor. But for your specific use case it's not that bad actually.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my github project for creating generic reducers. The solution I purpose will address many of the concerns you currently have.

[Redux-Reducer-Generator](https://github.com/Thuthinh/Redux-Reducer-Generator/blob/master/README.md)